# Should I consider GIN index for several columns?

Tags: postgresql, index, gin-index

In our application we have a field that can be used to match with several columns in our database. So if the user searches for `somestring` we will return all the rows `WHERE column1 = 'somestring' OR column2 = 'somestring'` etc. We are using Postgres.

I am wondering if it is viable to use `GIN` index for this purpose. Normally i see `GIN` indexes used for long and variable-length data, however. So I am wondering there is any point using them to index short, fixed length `tsvector`s or should I just index each column separately with a `BTREE` and let the planner handle the search.

Answer (score 2):

You can, with the aid of the btree_gin standard extension.  But there likely is not much point, as normal btree indexes on each column separately can also be used for this, using a BitmapOr planner node.

duplicate value compression is better in GIN indexes than in btree indexes, so if each column has many duplicate values the GIN index might be smaller than the sum of each btree index.

Comment: The question said that the index is on `tsvectors`, although it was not totally clear.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I thought he mentioned that just because he didn't know about btree_gin and so thought he needed tsvector as a workaround.